# iOS or Android app first for a startup

Tags: android, ios, mobile

First off I want to make the claim that I am in no way intending to pick a fight with either android fans or iOS fans, the reason I am asking the following question is because I am not bias in either device and would like to make a good decision for my startup, also I understand that this is a big debate that many have answered but many of those answers I have read seem to be dated given the information they provide.

Question:
I have a startup and I have completed the web app in rails, I am now looking to create a mobile app, (I don't want to use phonegap, etc ...only native code). I have studied both platforms and I see that android has a bigger adoption that iOS, but of course iOS controls usage share. My question is, based on the programming knowledge we know (ruby, python) and based on market share, what would be a better platform to develop first for? And which one do you find easier. I think I should also point out that if I do develop for android I will only strictly support (4.+).
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you´ll only support andorid > 4 then develop the iOS version first. I don't know you knowledge of iOS or android, so I can't tell you which one should be easier for you, for me iOS is easier. Furthermore, you have +-10 days since you upload the iOS version until they publish it, so you can use that days for the android version.

Comment: Those 10 days would be better spent promoting the app on forums or through your own web site. A rushed port in the days leading up to release sounds like a major commercial risk to me!

Comment: I don't mean he should finish in 10 days, but he has 10 extra days. BTW, if you know ruby, you can try rubymotion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a bigger overall market share for smartphones, but only ~40% of Android devices are running 4.0+ (source: http://www.inquisitr.com/467457/google-android-4-0-now-controls-40-marketshare/). That is an important factor for your decision. If you target the latest version of iOS, you'll probably get a bigger proportion of users able to use it. If your app becomes crazily popular, you'll have fewer iOS users screaming for legacy OS support.

You say you're writing stuff in Ruby and Python now, does this mean you've no experience of Objective-C or Java? If so, I'd guess that transitioning from a dynamically-typed language to either of those will be equally challenging at first.

Finally, how are you planning to raise revenue via your App? If it's a subscription service or a paid app, the commercial side of dealing with Google and Apple is near-enough identical. With Android, however, you have the option of including advertisements in your app to subsidise your app development as your business grows. This could be important if you want to grow a grass-roots following reluctant to pay up-front for an App.

Plenty of things to consider! If it were me, I would plan a sprint session writing an App for each platform and then evaluate my experience before deciding which development environment would get me to market quicker. You might discover that it's still too close to call, though.

Comment: Thanks I hadn't thought about doing a "sprint session", great idea thanks!

Comment: @Richard A. on iOS you have the advertisements option too

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target maximum audience than its Android for sure. As it holds 75% market share in 3rd quarter of 2012. And in some countries like China its around 90%.
Moreover, along with market share you should also keep
Rate of adoption in mind while picking a platform.  Which for Android is as good as it can be. Till date more than 50% of Android devices runs on 2.3 I.e gingerbread. 
And its decent enough to build any app.

Comment: If you include Gingerbread it's more like 80% of Android devices, but you may then have to write two distinct frontends for your app.

Comment: No you don't have to as an application written in 2.3 will run on all the versions that have come after it. And Gingerbread is not 80% it is around 50 only.

Comment: It really depends whether most of your target users are on Android or iOS. But for me, I find it a lot easier and cheaper to develop for Android and I make more money there than on iOS. If you develop for iOS you need a Mac computer and an iPhone for testing and development - both of which are quite expensive. Also Apple charges a developer fee of US$99 a year, whereas with Android there is a once off payment of US$25 to publish on Google Play, and you can develop on any PC. Plus Apple's app review process is tedious and time consuming. Also, you can just target Android 4.0 and above now.